# Core plot line graph start at origin

Tags: ios, core-plot

Currently, my graph looks like this -

[image]

However, I want the first x value to be origin. I mean "04\06" should be at the origin. Can some one please tell me how to do it. Thanks

Comment: have you tried setting plotAreaFrame's paddings?

Comment: Yes, but that moves the whole graph